# 警告が出る: 入力コネクションに不正な入力がありました

Tags: r

cv.csvのファイルを読み込もうとすると

```
 警告メッセージ: 
1:  read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
   入力コネクション 'C:/rdata/cv.csv' に不正な入力がありました 
2:  read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
3:  read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/rdata/a.xlsx'
```

となります
助けて下さい

Comment: `read.table()` に `skipNul = T` を追加すれば cv.csv ファイルを読み込む事ができるかもしれません。

Comment: @原田瑠嘉 さん、スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　警告メッセージだけだと回答者が実際にその警告を再現できず、適切な回答を示せないかもしれません。ヘルプセンターの[「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)のようにして、実際にお書きになったプログラム等を質問文に追記して頂けませんか？　質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

[【R】続・csvデータを読み込むときに出てくるエラーを解消したい。](http://demacassette2.hateblo.jp/entry/2017/07/12/232156) の記事が参考になるのではないでしょうか。